# Adding text to element arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, firebase, android-studio

I'm creating a listview of an element for my school's project and when I run the app it shows me the element's details. I want it to show a specific text but I can't find how to do it.
here is my java code:

```
private ArrayList<Playlist>playlists=new ArrayList<Playlist>();
ArrayAdapter<Playlist> adapter;

lvPlaylists=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPlaylists);
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<Playlist>(Playlists.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playlists);
lvPlaylists.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my function to get the items from the firebase cloud firestore to my arraylist

```
CollectionReference PlaylistsRef = db.collection("Users").document(Mail).collection("Playlists");
    PlaylistsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult())
                {
                    if(!task.getResult().getDocuments().isEmpty())
                    {
                        String PlaylistName= (String)documentSnapshot.get("Name");

                        PlaylistsRef.document(PlaylistName).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                if (documentSnapshot != null){
                                    Playlist playlist = new Playlist((String)documentSnapshot.get("Name"), (String)documentSnapshot.get("Genre"));
                                    playlists.add(playlist);
                                    lvPlaylists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                            Intent intent=new Intent(Playlists.this,PlaylistView.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("Name", adapter.getItem(position).getName());
                                            intent.putExtra("Genre", adapter.getItem(position).getGenre());
                                            intent.putExtra("PN", PN);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });`
```

Playlist:

```
public class Playlist implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String genre;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;

public Playlist(String name, String genre, ArrayList<Song> songs)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.genre=genre;
    this.songs=songs;
}

public Playlist(String name, String genre)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.genre=genre;
    this.songs=null;
}

public Playlist()
{
    this.name=null;
    this.genre=null;
    this.songs=null;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setGenre(String genre)
{
    this.genre=genre;
}

public String getGenre()
{
    return this.genre;
}

public ArrayList<Song> getSongs ()
{
    return this.songs;
}

public void addSong (Song song)
{
    songs.add(song);
}

public String ToString()
{
    return this.name+" "+this.genre;
}

public void removeSong(Song song)
{
    for(int i=0;i<this.songs.size();i++)
    {
        if(this.songs.get(i).getName()==song.getName())
        {
            this.songs.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

right now it shows me this when I run the app:
[shows me the item's details and I want text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw0VG.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the adapter class ?

Comment: I don't think I have it.. I didn't create a special adapter